# incomplete vector space of continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C([-1,1])$ be the vector space of continuous functions define on $[-1,1]$.

Show in the norm

$$\vert \vert f \vert \vert = \int_{-1}^1 \vert f(x) \vert dx$$

this vector space is not complete.

Does this mean to find a Cauchy sequence in $C([-1,1])$ that does not converge in $C([-1,1])$ under the above norm? Sort of lost then, so would my elements be continuous functions,

$$f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

any hints? can this be generalized to any closed and bounded $[a,b]$???

can I use $f_n:= x^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use $x^{n}$ becasue it converges to the zero function in this norm. Consider a piece-wise linear function which is $1$ for $x <\frac 1 2 $, $0$ for $x>\frac 1  2+\frac1  n$. The limit in norm in this case is a discontinuous function.

Comment: is this continuous a.e.?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame The limit function $f$ is continuous a.e. but there is not continuous function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e..

Comment: so would that suffice then?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame It does. I have produced a Cauchy sequence which does not converge to any element of $C[-1,1]$.